# How do you translate "Infoabend" into English?

Tags: german-to-english

How do you translate Infoabend in English?

[linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=infoabend) translates it as "information evening" which sounds odd to me

and [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=infoabend) doesn't even have an entry for it.

and "open house" is another kind of event, and is translated as "Tag der offenen Tür".

An Infoabend is usually just a more casual event usually with a presentation and time afterwards to ask questions and meet the people at a clinic, company, organization, etc.

Comment: [Pons](http://en.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=infoabend&l=deen&in=&lf=de&kbd=de) also uses "information evening" and it is used online very often: http://www.google.de/search?q=%22information+evening%22

Comment: This type of question is welcome at English Language & Usage SE. // I would say, for example, "I want to go to a **presentation** tomorrow evening about our town's Sister City.  Can you watch the kids for me, please?" // However, there is another sort of event that is called a "Meet and Greet." // There are lots of other possibilities.  For example, "Come prepared with all your questions about our school on Monday evening to the annual 'Meet the Principal' event.  Pizza will be served and there will be child care in the gym."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German *"[Infoabend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Infoabend)"* is a more colloquial or modern form for *"Informationsveranstaltung"* (when held in the evening). Depending on the context there are many possible translations to English, most closest may be:

> Welcome meeting
>   Information meeting

---

In a commercial setting we may also use

> Roadshow

In case its part of a project planning there is

> Kickoff meeting

The latter also exists as a loanword in German.

Comment: Further types of meetings that might fit here (depending upon the context) are "orientation meeting" (for newcomers, new employees etc.), "brown bag meeting" (for informal meeting during lunch or dinner).

Answer (score 2):

It might sound odd, but I've seen it used and it pretty much addresses what an "Infoabend" is.

I've also seen:

> Q and A meeting